# Does The Guardian's Path Passive Skill effect Spirit Per Second bonuses on gear and from skills?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

> While dual-wielding, you gain a 15% chance to dodge incoming attacks. While using a two-handed weapon, all Spirit generation is increased by 25%.

Does the 25% bonus only apply to Spirit generated from attacks, or does it also increase Spirit per second from gear and mantras by 25%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also increases spirit per second from gear AND mantras by 25%